# Implicit Differentiation of $x^2y+y^5\sec(x)=5$.

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

### Problem

I have began teaching myself Calc I and I've come across the following problem:

> Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the following:
>   $$x^2y+y^5\sec(x)=5.$$

I automatically presumed this was an implicit differentiation. However, since I'm somewhat new to implicit differentiation, my solution looks messy. It is below, and my question is: **Am I doing this right and are there ways I could improve (whether it be in terms of my notation, method, or something else)?**

### Solution

\begin{align}
x^2y+y^5\sec(x)&=5\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2y+y^5\sec(x)\right)&=\frac{d}{dx}5\\
\frac{d}{dx}x^2y+\frac{d}{dx}y^5\sec(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}5\\
2xy+x^2\frac{d}{dx}(y)+\frac{d}{dx}(y^5)\sec(x)+y^5\sec(x)\tan(x)&=0\\
2xy+x^2\frac{d}{dx}(y)+5y^4\frac{d}{dx}(y)\sec(x)+y^5\sec(x)\tan(x)&=0\\
x^2\frac{d}{dx}(y)+5y^4\frac{d}{dx}(y)\sec(x)&=-2xy-y^5\sec(x)\tan(x)\\
\frac{d}{dx}(y)\left(x^2+5y^4\sec(x)\right)&=-2xy-y^5\sec(x)\tan(x)\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-2xy-y^5\sec(x)\tan(x)}{x^2+5y^4\sec(x)}.
\end{align}

### Side question

How could I put this into Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Try "derivative of x^2*y + y^5*Sec[x] = 5" at WolframAlpha.

Comment: It ia fine. A bit too much detail. Two minor suggestions. Avoid $\frac{d}{dx}(y)$, use $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $y'$. And avoid specially things like $\frac{d}{dx}(y)\sec x$, you do tat sort of thing several times. Inevitably this will be at some stage by you, or someone else, as the derivative of the product.

Comment: I think I will choose $y'$ since it has the least amount of ambiguity, @AndréNicolas.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you, @Amzoti.

Comment: Limitless, you are welcome. I would also recommend seeing if you can figure out how to transform the problem and arrive at some of the alternate forms that WA provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2y+y^5\sec(x)=5.$$
$$2xy+x^2y'+5y^4y'\sec(x)+y^5\sec'x=0$$
$$y'(x^2+5y^4\sec x)=-2xy-y^5\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x }$$
$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2xy-y^5\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x }}{x^2+5y^4\sec x}$$

Comment: The denominator doesn't look right.

Comment: I just corrected it

Comment: I quite for this answer. +1

Comment: @BabakSorouh thanks!